# Unable Fetch data using pouchdb in mozilla latest browser using web

Tags: javascript

I have created db using pouchdb.Iam able to access the data in chrome but unable Access the data in mozilla latest browser.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Me too. Works in Safari and Chrome on my Mac.

Firefox was working a few weeks ago, now I'm getting these errors:

window.controllers/Controllers is deprecated. Do not use it for UA detection.
vendor.884175873da25bb4e526.js:40:95354
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
bundle.25bdeac6d2ce92b30461.js:1
h
https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/bundle.25bdeac6d2ce92b30461.js:1:1

https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/bundle.25bdeac6d2ce92b30461.js:1:36603
r
https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/manifest.9900c5a8eb329caf2817.js:1:96

https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/bundle.25bdeac6d2ce92b30461.js:1:457657
r
https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/manifest.9900c5a8eb329caf2817.js:1:96

https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/bundle.25bdeac6d2ce92b30461.js:1:386570
r
https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/manifest.9900c5a8eb329caf2817.js:1:96

https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/bundle.25bdeac6d2ce92b30461.js:1:96028
r
https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/manifest.9900c5a8eb329caf2817.js:1:96

https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/bundle.25bdeac6d2ce92b30461.js:1:501197
r
https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/manifest.9900c5a8eb329caf2817.js:1:96

https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/bundle.25bdeac6d2ce92b30461.js:1:507783
r
https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/manifest.9900c5a8eb329caf2817.js:1:96

https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/bundle.25bdeac6d2ce92b30461.js:1:371372
r
https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/manifest.9900c5a8eb329caf2817.js:1:96

https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/bundle.25bdeac6d2ce92b30461.js:1:259285
r
https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/manifest.9900c5a8eb329caf2817.js:1:96

https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/bundle.25bdeac6d2ce92b30461.js:1:624052
r
https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/manifest.9900c5a8eb329caf2817.js:1:96
window.webpackJsonp
https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/manifest.9900c5a8eb329caf2817.js:1:418

https://cherrypc.com:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/bundle.25bdeac6d2ce92b30461.js:1:1

Comment: Just tested and Firefox still works for me. Try: https://bloggr.exmer.com